# Maven release plugin 2.2.2 doesn't push to distributionmanagement

Tags: maven, distribution, maven-release-plugin, maven-scm-plugin

I had to update the maven release plugin from version 2.2.1 to 2.2.2 to get around a bug, but now, when doing a maven release, the files for the new version are not uploaded to my distribution management.

I have tried the following:

- `mvn release:prepare` & `mvn release:perform` with version 2.2.2 of the release-plugin:  Uploads the new SNAPSHOT-version
- `mvn release:prepare` with version 2.2.1, `mvn release:perform` with version 2.2.2: Uploads the new version (which is what i want)

So somehow the setup done by `mvn release:perform` with version 2.2.2 of the release plugin gets things wrong, but I really can't see why this happens.

**Update:** I took a quick look in my target\checkout folder, and there the pom-s where for the SNAPSHOT-version. So the wrong version is moved to checkout during release:prepare.

**Update #2:** I've narrowed it down to something git-related. The contents of the target\checkout folder comes from a git checkout. Since I've updated the version of the scm-plugin as well it must have something to do with this..

From pom.xml:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <preparationGoals>clean install</preparationGoals>
      <pushChanges>false</pushChanges>
    </configuration>
      <version>2.2.2</version>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>

[...]
<distributionManagement>
  <repository>
    <id>nexus-releases</id>
    <url>http://repository/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
  </repository>
  <snapshotRepository>
    <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
    <url>http://repository/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
  </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

I'm using maven 2.2.1.

Comment: The first recommendation i can give is to use Maven 3.0.4 instead of 2.2.1 furthermore go to an more up-to-date version of the maven-release-plugin. On the other hand i don't understand why are you defining preparationGoals and why you turned off pushing changes?

Comment: I am/was stuck with using mvn2 because of third party libraries that doesn't support mvn3, and are really tricky updating (the project is a bit of a mess..) Anyways, fixed this problem, will add answer with what needed to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by updating the maven-release-plugin to version 2.4. During release:perform it checked out a snapshot version and pushed this to the distribution management instead of the built version.

Comment: snapshot version means you are saying , inside trunk or inside tag.Because tags are created from -SNAPSHOT by release:prepare.I have the problem in release:perform.