# Maven Release without pushing to Nexus (aka maven central)

Tags: git, maven, nexus

I've got a java application that I want to follow the typical maven release cycle with, but I don't want or need to push the application to Nexus (or maven central).

When I run

```
mvn release:prepare release:perform -Darguments="-DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true"
```

I get an error during the perform stage that says the pom.xml file was missing the `<distributionManagement>` definitions required to push the built artifacts to NEXUS (our internal maven repo).

I'm using git and when I use `git log` I can see that all the other steps that I wanted to perform were performed properly.

- The pom.xml file was changed from 1.2-SNAPSHOT to 1.2 and a commit was performed and a git tag was created at to tag that release.
- The pom.xml file was then changed to 1.3-SNAPSHOT to ready the git branch to be used for subsequent development.

So... everything looks good.  **All I want to do is to tell maven not to try to do the push so the command completes without an error.**
*NOTE: A couple files from `release:prepare` were left around, one was `release.properties`, but I can live with manually deleting that if necessary.*

**Some solutions I'm looking for are:**

- You can't do that.
- Just take off the `release:perform` and only run `release:prepare`.  I'm testing this now.
- Add the flag -DmavenReleasePluginDontPushToNexus=true.  I'm making this up but wondering if there is a flag.

I've looked for solutions to all the above and haven't found an answer yet.

## Searching for solution

**Maven Release Plugin**

- The maven release plugin documentation is at http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/plugin-info.html.  **It looks like I don't want to use `release:perform` based on reading this!**
- Docs for `release:perform` goal.  http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/perform-release.html - pretty useless.
- https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-releasing.html - A pretty good guide on how to use the maven release plugin.

**Stack Overflow Searches**

- [How to setup the Maven release plugin with git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39573409/how-to-setup-the-maven-release-plugin-with-git) - Poor person never got his question answered.  Viewed 16K times!
- [Maven release plugin 2.2.2 doesn't push to distributionmanagement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975187/maven-release-plugin-2-2-2-doesnt-push-to-distributionmanagement) - This looked promising but basically says it should push and says to add `<distributionManagement>` elements to define where you want to push things to.  Since I don't want to do this I'm not adding this definition.
- [Hudson and maven-release-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831080/hudson-and-maven-release-plugin) - OP was trying figure out how to use maven release plugin with hudson.  It didn't help.
- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmaven%5D+release - a search for questions with the maven tag and the word release.  Too many results to be useful (over 10,000).
- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmaven%5D+release+push - Now down to 300 results, better but I didn't find an answer.

My guess is that this has been asked and answered before but so far I can't find it.

Comment: It looks like running ONLY `mvn release:prepare` does what I want, and then I run `mvn release:clean` to delete the files created during the prepare step.

Comment: Have you checked `-DdryRun` https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#dryRun

Comment: @khmarbaise, I have used that `-DdryRun` in the past.   How will that help in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirm, the `release:prepare` phase will:

- Verify that there are no uncommitted changes in the workspace.
- Prompt the user for the desired tag, release and development version names.
- Modify and commit release information into the pom.xml file.
- Tag the entire project source tree with the new tag name.

The only missing step from `release:perform` that you might need is the increment of the version to the next SNAPSHOT, transforming the release version to a new snapshot, in order to prepare for the next batch of work.
[Using `version:set` will be required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5726599/6309).

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by changing the goal to install, by default it is deploy:

```
<artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <goals>install</goal>
</configuration>
```

Also, I think you can ignore perform totally, because the updating and committing of BOTH release version and new development versions are done by prepare step:
[maven release plugin doc](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html)

Comment: Or just use the property `goals` if you don't want to modify your POM file for some reason.  
**Example command:** `mvn release:perform -Dgoals=install`  
**Link to param docs:** [release:perform goal docs](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html)

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar need, but I wanted to make a released copy in my local repository (`~/.m2/repository/`).

First, I got rid of running `release:perform` goal, only leaving `mvn release:clean release:prepare` as a command. It increases the version to both stable and next development versions, does all the git commits and pushes.

Then, in plugin's `configuration` in `pom.xml`, I added `preparationGoals` with `install`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <preparationGoals>clean install</preparationGoals>
        <projectVersionPolicyId>SemVerVersionPolicy</projectVersionPolicyId>
        […]
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

so that while performing the release, after preparing new stable version, this version is saved to local Maven repository.

This parameter is mentioned in Plugin documentation pages:

- https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/run-goals-before-commit.html
- https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#preparationGoals

Note: I also added:
`<projectVersionPolicyId>SemVerVersionPolicy</projectVersionPolicyId>`
so that I use „SemVer format and increase minor element when resolving the development version” instead of patch part (the default) – it increases the 2nd version part, instead of the 3rd version part, [as in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76059945/3673367).